# Replace every character but which is in my regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I found [this regex](https://regexr.com/3cg7r) which validates Instagram usernames

`/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/gim`

What I'm trying to do is to replace all characters which not match my regex

```
let regex = new RegExp(/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/gim);
const filteredString = replace(text, regex, '');
```

I tried to add `?!` at the start as a negative lookahead but no luck

Comment: `const filteredString = text.replace(/[^\w.]+/g, '');`

Comment: What's the reason for using `[^\W]`? It's the same as `\w`

Answer (score 1):

Removing all the aprts that don't mach is the same as keeping the matches.

Instead of using `replace` you can use `match` and add all the matches to your `filteredString`, like shown below:

```js
    let text = `riegiejeyaranchen
riegie.jeyaranchen
_riegie.jeyaranchen
.riegie
riegie..jeyaranchen
riegie._.jeyaranchen
riegie.
riegie.__`;
    let regex = new RegExp(/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/gim);
    let filteredString = '';
    text.match(regex).forEach(value =>
    {
        filteredString += value + '\r\n';
    });
    console.log(filteredString);
```

Of course the `\r\n` is optional (just places one on each line).

Now you get a string where non matches are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the regex `/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/`, the name must not have consecutive dots, no leading and trailing dots, and have max 30 word/dot chars. This code cleans up names accordingly:

```js
[
  'f',
  'foobar',
  '_foo.bar',
  '_foo..bar',
  '_foo...bar',
  '_foo.bar.',
  '.foo.bar',
  'foo<$^*>bar',
  '123456789012345678901234567890',
  '1234567890123456789012345678901'
].forEach(name => {
  let clean = name
    .replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.')  // reduce multiple dots to one dot
    .replace(/^\.+/, '')      // remove leading dots
    .replace(/\.+$/, '')      // remove trailing dots
    .replace(/[^\w\.]/g, '')  // remove non word/dot chars
    .replace(/^(.{30}).+/, '$1'); // restrict to 30 chars
  console.log(name + ' => ' + clean);
});
```

Output:

```
f => f
foobar => foobar
_foo.bar => _foo.bar
_foo..bar => _foo.bar
_foo...bar => _foo.bar
_foo.bar. => _foo.bar
.foo.bar => foo.bar
foo<$^*>bar => foobar
123456789012345678901234567890 => 123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901 => 123456789012345678901234567890
```

Note that the original regex requires at least one char. You need to test for empty string after cleanup.

Comment: @Poul Bak: Does this answer address your needs? If so would you care to accept it? If not, add some more details to your question.